# Nginx hangs "http://localhost" in docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, networking

Why doesn't this simple docker compose answer to `http://localhost` ?

```
version: "3.3"
networks:
  mynet: null
services:
  front-end:
    image: nginx
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

It works fine when I run `curl 127.0.0.1`.
It doesn't answer when I run `curl localhost`.
It works fine if I comment this line in `/etc/hosts`:

```
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

This problem occurs only with `docker stack`. Everything works fine when use `docker run`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by disabling IPv6 issuing these commands:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

And adding the following at the bottom of the file `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Reference: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-linux/